# Mezclar dos Cadenas c++

Tags: c++

Como puedo hacer para mezclar dos cadenas en c++

Ejemplo:

```
Cadena 1 : HOLA

Cadena 2 : ADIOS

Resultado: HAODLIAOS
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y muéstranos que llevas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues muy facil

```
string cadn="";
if(n<=m){
   int i = 0;
   for(; i < n;i++)
      if(i%2==0||i==0)
         cadn+=cad1[i];
      else
         cadn+=cad2[i];
   for(;i<m;i++)
      cadn+=cad2[i];
}
else
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < m;i++)
       if(i%2==0||i==0)
         cadn+=cad2[i];
       else
         cadn+=cad1[i];
    for(;i<n;i++)
       cadn+=cad1[i];
}
cout << cadn;
```

Ahora la explicacion de que hace cada cosa primero que nada **n** y **m** son los tamaños respectivos de cada cadena. Comparas cual es mas grande y empiezas por la otra a mezclar una de cada una como me fije que querias... Luego te va o no a quedar un resto en la mas grande eso simplemente lo agregas... Y en caso contrario bueno por logica se deduce... Espero que esto te sirva cualqier cosa me la dejas en el comentario

Answer (score 2):

Basta con ir extrayendo el primer caracter de cada cadena y añadirlo al resultado. Paramos cuando ambas cadenas están vacías:

```
std::string cadena1 = "HOLA";
std::string cadena2 = "ADIOS";
std::string resultado;

while( !cadena1.empty() || !cadena2.empty() )
{
  resultado += cadena1.front();
  resultado += cadena2.front();
  cadena1.erase(0, 1);
  cadena2.erase(0, 1);
}

std::cout << resultado;
```